# Getting a 404 error deploying war. No error deploying jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm getting a 404 error when trying to access application deployed with Tomcat Manager.

It's a Spring Boot Java app.

This is how I'm doing:

1. Open http://localhost:8080/manager/html
2. Select myfile.war in "war file to deploy" and click "deploy"
3. The application successfully deploys. It becomes listed in the list of applications. I can click to Stop and Start it just fine.
4. Then I click the application link in the list to open it in the browser
   It goes to
   http://localhost:8080/myapp
   But it gives a 404 error

No error in the Catalina logs.

The interesting part is:

- If instead of creating a .war I create a .jar, stop tomcat and double click the jar, it installs it and the application executes correctly when going to the same link: http://localhost:8080/myapp.
- When I double-click the jar it creates a javaw.exe process in Windows Task Manager. But when I stop that, start Tomcat and deploy the application using Tomcat manager, this javaw.exe process never starts. So I'm thinking that could be the reason.

In both cases using the same file name. Just changing the extension:

myapp.jar and myapp.war

Environment Variables:

JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\RedHat\java-11-openjdk-11.0.19-1

Path: %JAVA_HOME%\bin

Tomcat version is 10.1.12

Spring boot 2.7.13

Comment: Quite confusing. Firstly, you do know that javaw.exe is nothing to do with webapps *per se* but just for executing java apps? Nothing is *installed* when you double click a jar. It will simply be run (usually) by javaw.exe. Now, that app *might* create a web server that you can access via your browser. Now your app *might* also be able to be packaged, if a webapp, as a war file. Two different things

Comment: @g00se Sorry if confusing. Feel free to ask anything needed to clarify. It is a REST API. When deploying it generating a jar it works. When double clicking the jar it starts javaw.exe process. But instead of jar I need to deploy it using war (for other reasons). But that is not working. When I upload it using Tomcat manager and try to open the same link in the browser I get a 404 error. The only difference I noticed is that in this case javaw.exe is not started. So was wondering if it should.

Comment: A war is an entirely different beast. How are you building your war?

Comment: Both the war and jar I'm building in Spring Tool Suite. In STS > right click projet name > Run As > Maven Build… > In “Goals” type: clean package -DskipTests > Run.  The only difference is that change pom.xml to either one in <packaging>war</packaging>

Comment: There could be many reasons for the 404. What does the Tomcat log say *when you deploy*? *The only difference I noticed is that in this case javaw.exe is not started. So was wondering if it should.* Again, javaw has nothing to do with webapps (normally)

Comment: There are no error in the catalina logs. ```org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\webapps\myapp.war] has finished in [7,724] ms```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255006/discussion-between-g00se-and-jkfe).

Comment: In your main class with the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation, did you extend from `SpringBootServletInitializer` ? If not that might be your problem. Packaging in a Jar file will create and initialize beans automatically and if you want to use a war file you need to tell to bind the beans from the application context to the tomcat.

Comment: @Tavo Sanchez Just need to add ```extends SpringBootServletInitializer``` to ```public class MyApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer``` or need anything else like overriding a method? I tried just adding the ```extends``` and had no effect.

Comment: You need to override the configure method. Here is the spring [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.traditional-deployment.war) for reference

Comment: @Tavo Sanchez I did as informed in the documentation you shared. Still not working.

Comment: I tested on Tomcat to version 9.0.76 and it worked. For some reason it does not work on v 10.1.12.

Comment: Might be a path issue. Did you set a context path in your application.properties (or yaml)? If not, I guess the `/myapp` part of the URL comes from a Controller/RestController. In that case, on Tomcat, the URL should be `http://localhost:8080/myapp/myapp`

Comment: @grekier Yes, I did. Also had already tried to access the path you suggested.